# How are momentum and position operators dependent on the chosen inertial frame?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum

How are momentum and position operators in quantum mechanics dependent on the chosen inertial frame of reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The are defined just once you have fixed an *inertial reference frame* and a *Cartesian orthonormal coordinate system* co-moving with it. Changing inertial reference frame, the new operators are related with the initial ones by means of a strongly continuous **projective-unitary representation** of (connected) Galileo group $G \ni g \mapsto U_g$,
$$P'_k = U_g P_k U_g^\dagger\:, \quad X'_k = U_g X_k U_g^\dagger$$
The representation is *projective* in the sense that $U_gU_{g'} = e^{i\alpha_M(g,g')}U_{gg'}$ where the real phase $\alpha_M(g,g')$ depends on the total mass $M$ of the physical system and there is no way to get rid of that phase (differently from the case of Poincaré group).

For instance a boost transformation $g_v$, at $t=0$, i.e., $x\to x'$, $p\to p'+Mv$ produces 
$$U_{g_v} P_k U_{g_v}^\dagger = P_k + Mv_kI\:,\quad U_{g_v} X_k U_{g_v}^\dagger = X_k$$